# Getting - Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visit any OP's profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I am getting  Oops! Something Bad Happened!  when visit any OP's profile. I tried in many stack exchange sites.

[Oops! Something Bad Happened!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBke8.jpg)

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Comment: Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 , Window 7

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you give a link to a profile where that happened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/1664899/user1664899

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/7365/eciurleo

Comment: Those are links to the error page... Try http://stackoverflow.com/users/1664899/user1664899

Comment: Yes when I click on Op's profile , it is generating link like that.

Comment: I am getting same error when tried your given link.

Comment: OK - try clearing your SO/SE cookies. Something there might be corrupt.

Comment: Getting same error still. I cleared cookies and cache both. I tried in firefox as well..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96137/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-oded).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So, it looks like one of our web servers threw a wobbly (technical term).

It's been given a kick and appears to be back and running.

This is likely the reason for the issues you have seen, though it would be great if you can confirm things are back to normal now.

Comment: Yep , It seems now everything normal. Thanks a lot..

Comment: "It's been given a kick" pffft, I've always found that a Falcon Punch is more effective.

Comment: @Oded i am still facing the same issue

Comment: @saurabhkamble - when you access any user profile? Is that happening on all sites?

Comment: @Oded clicked on the profile link given in the comment of the question using chrome browser os windows 8

Comment: @oded just checked your chat with helping hands its working properly sorry for the confusion as they are error links

Comment: Just curious, **what type of laptop** is it that is used in all these pictures? It looks old https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/681791902.jpg