# Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visiting some profiles

Tags: bug, profile-page

When trying to open profiles for some [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) I am getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error.

For example I can't open this profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo,

but can open this https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin

Tried in Firefox and Chrome. Probably related to [Getting - Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visit any OP's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311080/getting-oops-something-bad-happened-when-visit-any-ops-profile) asked 4 days ago, but that question is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Can reproduce - noticed it when visiting a user account with special characters in their name.  I'm somewhat relieved to know that it isn't limited to that use case.

Comment: Seems to be fixed.  Sunday is traditionally the day that they do 'dangerous' things, the "oops" message is usually triggered by a dbase query timeout of failure.  The devs keep a close eye on these errors so they tend to disappear automagically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to open several top profiles, including the one OP linked.  They all worked for me.

Whatever happened, it appears to be fixed for now.

Comment: Seems to be fixed. Can't reproduce it anymore too.