# Can't access any user profiles anymore: Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, profile-page

I am getting Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visit any OP's profile. I tried in many stack exchange sites.

related: [Getting - Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visit any OP's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311080/getting-oops-something-bad-happened-when-visit-any-ops-profile)

Comment: I'm from Canada and I can't access my own profile either, but it's probably my fault I can't access them. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've had two separate periods of time today where I was unable to reach SO (including this one)

Comment: Looks to be working again.

Comment: Answered on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295476). It's fixed now.