# Can not load my Profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

Stack Overflow is working fine, but I can not seem to load my own profile.
When I try to view my own profile it is saying:

[image]

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Is this a known bug? Or am I just unlucky and it'll be fixed soon enough?

Related to:
[Getting - Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visit any OP's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311080/getting-oops-something-bad-happened-when-visit-any-ops-profile)

Comment: Did you also receive something like this : "We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.

It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.stackoverflow.com."? 
I think its a stackoverflow issue, probably updating the profile section.

Comment: Yes that is the error I got, updated question with Error image.